# Problem with testing iOS App on device

Tags: iphone, xcode, testing, code-signing-entitlements

Yesterday I made myself a new my first App ID, all Certificates and downloaded and installed them. (As shown in the videos). As I wanted to test my App on my device (I set it up in the Organizer) I got an Error :

```
Validation[28932:607] *** Warning: Defaulting to the standard codesign tool
warning: Unable to extract entitlements from application: /Users/maxstottrop/Desktop/gefahrschutz/build/Release-iphoneos/gefahrschutz.app (-19045)
Unable to validate your application. - (null).
```

Any help?

PS: Yeah, I searched the forums and also started a new project. Nothing changed. Thanks in advance for your help.

// **Edit:**

I tried it first with the entitlements.plist while (finally) downloading Xcode 4. It didn't worked for me but when i tried it on XCode 4 with 4.3 if works. I guess it was just an issue with Xcode 3. But nevertheless thanks for your quick answers.

Comment: Are you using Xcode 4? You may try Xcode for to see if it fixes your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not a message I'm familiar with but a couple of suggestions;-

Make sure you are using the **debug** and **device** configuration (assuming you've not changed them from the template) when compiling and deploying during development. The file path above seems to suggest you are using a release configuration which is really for distribution. You should use that when submitting to Apple.

The debug configuration needs to have a file called "Entitlements.plist". In it, a value called get-task-allow need to be set to YES so that the debugger can connect to the instance of your App running on the device. I've had to create this file manually on occasion.

See if that helps.